# Iphone 4, IOS 7.1.2; Facebook Messenger App

Tags: facebook

I have iPhone 4, ios 7.1.2 and accidently deleted facebook messenger and don't have a backup of the app and now I can't reinstall because of 7.1.2. How can I get it back on my iphone? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can download it using iTunes store on your PC using the same iCloud account as your phone. Then, in your iPhone go to App Store click update and view purchased items. From there you can install back acebook messenger. Good luck!!!

Comment: The version of Messenger on the App Store requires iOS 8 or above.  How will the OP install it on their iPhone that has iOS 7.1.2?

Comment: @fsb Apple allows you to download the last supported version of an app if the app has changed the minimum supported iOS version. As long as Facebook didn't explicitly turn this feature off. http://iphone.appleinsider.com/articles/13/09/17/apples-ios-app-store-now-offers-last-compatible-versions-of-apps-for-older-devices

Comment: Yes, if the developer allows it and still supports that version.  I don't know explicitly, but anything made for iOS 7.1.2 is so old now that the OP would be lucky if it works.  Either way, the answer should've indicated this info but it didn't.  My point to the new user was to have them edit their answer to include this info.